# How can I fetch GAE logs using API and store on local machine?

Tags: java, logging, google-app-engine

How can I write some java code for local machine to fetch logs from various GAE apps (at least from one) and write it to a file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Logs Java API to download the appengine code pragmatically. Refere this: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/logs/

OR

You can download the log data to a file on your computer using `appcfg.sh`. To download logs to a file named `mylogs.txt`, use the request_logs action, as follows:

`./appengine-java-sdk/bin/appcfg.sh request_logs myapp/war mylogs.txt`

More Info: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp#Downloading_Logs

Comment: Thanks for links but here is what I'm willing to do. How can I get logs from http://twiliosandbox.appspot.com/ to a local java app??